# cassandra:sorting problem，ordering is wrong

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a question about Cassandra. At present, "entities_by_time" is ok on the 18-bit uuid through column1 sorting, but there is something wrong with uuid ascending to the 19-bit sorting. Please help me.

```
cqlsh:minds> select * from entities_by_time where key='activity:user:990192934408163330' order by column1 desc limit 10;
 key                              | column1            | value
----------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 999979571363188746 | 999979571363188746
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 999979567064027139 | 999979567064027139
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 999979562764865555 | 999979562764865555
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 999979558465703953 | 999979558465703953
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 999979554170736649 | 999979554170736649
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 999979549871575047 | 999979549871575047
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 999979545576607752 | 999979545576607752
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 999979541290029073 | 999979541290029073
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 999979536990867461 | 999979536990867461
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 999979532700094475 | 999979532700094475

cqlsh:minds> select * from entities_by_time where key='activity:user:990192934408163330' order by column1 asc limit 10;

 key                              | column1             | value
----------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1000054880351555598 | 1000054880351555598
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1000054884671688706 | 1000054884671688706
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1000054888966656017 | 1000054888966656017
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1000054893257429005 | 1000054893257429005
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1000054897552396308 | 1000054897552396308
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1000054901843169290 | 1000054901843169290
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1000054906138136577 | 1000054906138136577
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1000054910433103883 | 1000054910433103883
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1000054914723876869 | 1000054914723876869
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1000054919010455568 | 1000054919010455568


CREATE TABLE minds.entities_by_time (
    key text,
    column1 text,
    value text,
    PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (column1 ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'enabled': 'false'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Through inquiry, it is found that in Cassandra, 1007227353832624141 is less than 963426376394739730. Why?

Comment: "something wrong" is vague.  Help the less familiar readers understand the problem by elaborating on exactly what you see that is wrong.  Also, consider using preformatting tools to format your error message.  Edit your question and look at the formatting help.  It will mono-space things, which is especially useful when table-like data is being presented.

Comment: They both look like they're sorted correctly.  Can you elaborate a little on what you expected to see differently?

Comment: The sort order is correct. Review all digits, not just, say, the last 4 or 5 in the column value.

Comment: Found by sorting "column1".
Using desc sort, "999979571363188746" is the first,

Using asc sorting, "1000054880351555598" is the first.

But "1000054880351555598" is bigger than "999979571363188746".

Comment: @JimWartnick Found by sorting "column1". Using desc sort, "999979571363188746" is the first, Using asc sorting, "1000054880351555598" is the first. But "1000054880351555598" is bigger than "999979571363188746".

Comment: What is the column data type of "column1" . If it's text, I could see this being the case because 1 comes before 9 no matter how many "digits" there are in the string. My guess is that your column1 is text, not numeric.

Comment: share full schema please

Comment: Not sure which Cassandra version you are on, but don't use `COMPACT STORAGE` anymore.  In fact, it has been shown to *hurt* performance in Cassandra 3.

Answer (score 1):

Good call Chris!  The table definition tells it all!  I recreated your table and ran queries sorting in both directions:

```
flynn@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM entities_by_time
     WHERE key='activity:user:990192934408163330'  ORDER BY column1 DESC;

 key                              | column1             | value
----------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------
 activity:user:990192934408163330 |  999979571363188746 |  999979571363188746
 activity:user:990192934408163330 |  999979567064027139 |  999979567064027139
 activity:user:990192934408163330 |  963426376394739730 |  963426376394739730
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1007227353832624141 | 1007227353832624141
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1000054884671688706 | 1000054884671688706
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1000054880351555598 | 1000054880351555598

(6 rows)

flynn@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM entities_by_time
     WHERE key='activity:user:990192934408163330'  ORDER BY column1 ASC;

 key                              | column1             | value
----------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1000054880351555598 | 1000054880351555598
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1000054884671688706 | 1000054884671688706
 activity:user:990192934408163330 | 1007227353832624141 | 1007227353832624141
 activity:user:990192934408163330 |  963426376394739730 |  963426376394739730
 activity:user:990192934408163330 |  999979567064027139 |  999979567064027139
 activity:user:990192934408163330 |  999979571363188746 |  999979571363188746

(6 rows)
```

So to your question...

> in Cassandra, 1007227353832624141 is less than 963426376394739730. Why?

**Simply put, because 9 > 1, that's why.**

Your table definition clusters on `column1`, which is a TEXT/UTF8 string and **not** a numeric.  Essentially, Cassandra is sorting strings the only way it knows how - in ASCII-betical order, which is *not* alpha-numeric order.

Store your numerics as numerics, and sorting will behave in ways that are more predictable.